# Given $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, Prove $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(mx)} = \frac{1}{m} $ for $ m >0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> Given $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(mx)} = \frac{1}{m} $ for $ m >0$.

I can prove that this is true when looking at the limit from the left and right, but I have no idea how to incorporate the $\frac{\sin x}{x}$identity. Any assistance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360449/limit-of-sin-nx-mx-as-x-approaches-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(mx)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}x}{\frac{\sin(mx)}x}=\frac1m\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}x}{\frac{\sin(mx)}{mx}}.$$

Comment: (new to calculus) How were you able to pull out a $\frac{1}{m}$ from the limit, and how does doing that turn ${\sin(x)}$ into $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$?

Comment: I have added more information. Is it clear now?

Comment: Partly, but I'm still confused as to how ${\sin(x)}$ becomes $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and what purpose it serves.

Comment: For any three numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, with $b,c\neq0$, you have$$\frac ab=\frac{\frac ac}{\frac bc}.$$And the purpose is to be able to use the information that I have, which consists of$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1.$$

Comment: Awesome, I see why you did that now. I'm still a bit unsure about where the $\frac{1}{m}$ came from and what you did between the second and third step.

Comment: It comes from $\displaystyle\frac{\sin(mx)}x=m\frac{\sin(mx)}{mx}$.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(mx)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{x}{\sin(mx)}  = \frac{1}{m}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{mx}{\sin(mx)}  = \frac{1}{m}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{mx}{\sin(mx)} = \frac{1}{m}$